# about android intent action

Tags: android, android-intent

Current I am working in intent; however, I got some problems.

The thing is, I have two apps, A and B. The lunchmode of B is android:launchMode="singleTop".

Now, I want to pass an intent from A to B, said "sdcard/Android"(a directory path). After that, A will be finished and B will be created/resumed/onNewintent. At the first time, B will receive an intent string "sdcard/Android", which is exactly I want.

Then I press the home button to the launcher and open A again then pass a new data, said "sdcard/Music", to B. However, the problems is occured, B will not get the string "sdcard/Music", instead, B's intent data is still "sdcard/Android".

I expect the second time A pass the data to B, the onNewintent method will be called in B. Are there any wrongs? How can I pass the correct data to B in the second time?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Log.i("TAG", intent.getStringExtra("path"));
}
```

I know that I should overwrite the onNewIntent. At first time, the B will get into the onCreate method. On the second time, I expectd it get into the onNewIntent method; however, it get into the onResumed method..!

Answer (score 2):

The method `onNewIntent(...)` isn't called the first time for your `Activity B` it is only called on the second and further times that `Activity B` is started.

You can 're-write' the original `Intent` by doing something like the following...

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // The intent parameter here will be the original `Intent` the first
    // time Activity B is started. It will be the new Intent after that
    // as onNewIntent(...) re-writes it with the call to setIntent(...)
}
```

Comment: The problem is, B never get into the onNewIntent method! Why?

Comment: Don't call `onNewIntent(...)` directly and don't use `getIntent()` to pass it the existing `Intent` - that is exactly what you don't want to do. The method `onNewIntent(...)` is called automatically by the Android framework and you shouldn't call it yourself.

Comment: So, how can I pass the intent without using getIntent?  Intent intent = getIntent(); then pass intent..?

Comment: Look at my answer again. In `onNewIntent(...)` I call `setIntent(intent)` and then in `onResume()` I call `handleIntent(getIntent())`. The method `onNewIntent(...)` will always be called BEFORE `onResume()`. If the `Activity` is being started again and is `singleTop` then `onNewIntent(...)` is called. If it's the first time that the `Activity` has been started then it will go to `onResume()` immediately. Either way, if you use the model I've shown then the `handleIntent(...)` method will receive the correct `Intent`.